# extract and convert string into decimal number using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new at excel VB and seek assistant in the following problem below:

I have a column A with following values below:

```
column A
"VL50s"
"M50s"
"H50s"
"VL50s"
"H50s"
```

I would like to extract the numbers and run the following arithmetic function below into coloumn B.

```
key:
x is a number
VLx --> (x) + 1
Mx -->(x) + 2
Hx --> (x) + 3
```

the output should look like the following using the key above:

```
coloumn B
51
52
53
51
53
```

I would like to ask how would i go about doing this function in VBA.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Are the letters irrelevant? You just want to basically drop them off and use only the numbers on the right? Will there ever be a patterns like `[letters][numbers][letters][numbers]`?

Comment: there are many combination of string and numeric values in this column hence no specific rule can be applied.  thank you for helping.

Comment: Is the 's' on the end important?

Comment: @user1574185 - Did any of these answers help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you say the number of letter/number combos is much greater than in your example I think this is a problem for VBA and not a worksheet function. A WS function would become to hard to maintain and to beastly very quickly.

I made these 4 functions. The `GetCharArray` function parses the text of the string you pass it to return that text as an array of characters (even though BA doesn't have a `char` type just a `string` type so I am returning a string. Same idea)

Then given that we can call `GetNumberFromChars` to get the `50` from `VL50s` and call `GetLeftMostLetters` to get the `VL` from `VL50s`.

Then is some worksheet I made a named range called `keys` where column 1 of the range is letters like "VL", "H", "M" ... and the corresponding value associated with it is in column 2. It would look like

```
Col1    Col2
VL      1
M       2
H       3
...     ...
```

We can use the `vlookup` worksheet function with the `Range("keys")` and the result of `GetLeftMostLetters` to find the number that should be added to the result of `GetNumberFromChars`.

```
Function GetNewNumber(inString As String) As Double
    Dim searchString As String, numberToAddFromKeys As Double, numberToAddToFromCell As Long, cellChars() As String

    cellChars = GetCharArray(inString)
    searchString = GetLeftMostLetters(cellChars)
    numberToAddToFromCell = GetNumberFromChars(cellChars)

    'use the keys named range where column 1 is your letters ("VL","H"...)
    'and column 2 is the corresponding value for that letter set
    numberToAddFromKeys = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(searchString, Range("keys"), 2, 0)

    GetNewNumber = CDbl(numberToAddFromKeys) + CDbl(numberToAddToFromCell)
End Function


Function GetNumberFromChars(inChars() As String) As Long
    Dim returnNumber As String, i As Long, numberStarted As Boolean

    For i = 1 To UBound(inChars)
        If IsNumeric(inChars(i)) Then
            If Not numberStarted Then numberStarted = True
            returnNumber = returnNumber & inChars(i)
        Else
            If numberStarted Then
                'this will ignore that "s" on the end of your sample data
                'hopefully that's what you need
                GetNumberFromChars = returnNumber
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function

Function GetLeftMostLetters(inChars() As String) As String
    Dim returnString As String, i As Long

    For i = 1 To UBound(inChars)
        If Not IsNumeric(inChars(i)) Then
            returnString = returnString & inChars(i)
        Else
            GetLeftMostLetters = returnString
        End If
    Next
End Function


Function GetCharArray(inText As String) As String()
    Dim s() As String, i As Long
    ReDim s(1 To Len(inText))

    For i = 1 To UBound(s)
      s(i) = Mid$(inText, i, 1)
    Next
    GetCharArray = s
End Function
```

So it can be used as such...

```
Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
'set this range to your actual range. 

Set rng = Sheets("your sheet name").Range("A1:A5")       
For Each cell In rng
    'put this resulting value wherever you want.
    Debug.Print GetNewNumber(cell.Value)
Next cell
```

Comment: Dear @Brad, Thank so much for your reply and solution to my problem. Apology for the late response, i did not release this post had been posted with solutions, hence i tried to learn the vba programming language and implemented my own solution. thank you so much for your time and help, as your code worked great for the given example. Thanks million.

Comment: You're very welcome :) I'm happy its working for you and that you are working with VBA now :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to use VBA for that, you can use a (very ugly) formula to determine this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "VL",""), "M",""), "H", ""), 
    "s", "") + IF(LEFT(A1, 2) = "VL", 1, IF(LEFT(A1, 1) = "M", 2, 
    IF(LEFT(A1,1) = "H", 3, 0)))
```

In reality this formula should be on one line, but I've broken it up here so that it's readable.  Place the formula in cell B1, and then copy it down to any other cells you need.  It strips out all instances of "VL", "M", "H" and "s", and then adds the extra number based on the left 1 or 2 characters of the A cell.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the first number found in the input value:

```
Function GetNumber(val)
    Dim re As Object
    Dim allMatches
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Pattern = "(\d+)"
    re.ignorecase = True
    re.Global = True
    Set allMatches = re.Execute(val)
    If allMatches.Count > 0 Then
        GetNumber = allMatches(0)
    Else
        GetNumber = ""
    End If
End Function
```

EDIT: just noticed your question title says "decimal" numbers - will your values have any decimal places, or all they all whole numbers?

Answer (score 0):

This will return the first number found (including decimal numbers, negative numbers, numbers with thousands separators).

It returns a string, but you can change output type for Single, Double or Currency as needed.

You can also specify the optional decimal_separator argument in case your region uses `,` as decimal separator instead of `.` .

```
Function Extract_decimal_number(s As String, Optional decimal_separator As String = ".") As String
    Static re As RegExp
    
    If re Is Nothing Then Set re = New RegExp
    re.IgnoreCase = True
    re.Global = True
    If decimal_separator = "," Then
        s = Replace(s, ".", "") 'Remove thousands separators
        re.Pattern = "(-?\d+,?\d*)"
    Else
        s = Replace(s, ",", "") 'Remove thousands separators
        re.Pattern = "(-?\d+.?\d*)"
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Extract_decimal_number = re.Execute(s)(0)
End Function
```